# Why can't I use the command prompt after running a batch file on it?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I have a batch file that simply runs an exe file. I want to be able to open the command prompt, run the batch file, then... I want to type another command in the command prompt.

here is the code that is in the batch file called "sublime.bat":
"C:\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe"

I open cmd in the directory with my bat file and I type:
"sublime.bat"

It works by opening sublime text but the cmd cursor starts flashing and I can no longer type anything until I close sublime text.

I want to be able to open sublime text and type commands out while still having sublime text open. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Type `start /?` to understand the different ways of starting programs. So `Start "" C:\sublime.bat "C:\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command prompt doesn't execute a further line, while a command is on execution. It executes commands serially, not parallelly. So if you want a command to be executed cmd should return from executing previous one.

Here, in `"sublime.bat"` you have called a batch file which contains a command of executing another program. So, cmd waits for the result of executing the bat file and thus stuck there.

You can use `start "/k" "C:\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe"` in your `"sublime.bat"`. This holds only the `start` command and cmd gets free after starting the file.

Comment: This helped a lot. Thank you so much!